# If ${\rm ker}T\cap C_\infty=\{0\}$, prove that $T(C_\infty)=T(C)_\infty$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Let $\mathbb{E_1,E_2}$ be two finite dimension Euclidean spaces. $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{E_1,E_2})$ is a linear map. Given a closed set $C\subset\mathbb{E_1}$. Let $C_\infty$ denote the [asymptotic cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit#Asymptotic_cones) of $C$, i.e
\begin{align}
C_\infty=\{v:\exists \{x_i\}\subset C,\exists \{t_i\geq0\}\to0,t_ix_i\to v\}
\end{align}
If ${\rm ker}T\cap C_\infty=\{0\}$, prove that $T(C_\infty)=T(C)_\infty$.

One side is simple. Now for the side: $T(C)_\infty\subset T(C_\infty):$ If $v\in T(C)_\infty$ then there exists $\{x_i\},\{t_i\}$ such that $t_iT(x_i)=T(t_ix_i)\to v$. Now I want to show that $T^{-1}v\in C_\infty$. One theorem states that if ${\rm ker}T\cap C_\infty=\{0\}$, then $T(C)$ is closed. But I have no further ideas how to prove $\{t_ix_i\}$ converges to some element.

Comment: What does the zero mean in $\ker(T)\cap C_\infty = 0$

Comment: @gist076923 A typo, it should be {0}, I have edited.

Comment: I was able to show $\{t_ix_i\}$ was bounded. Think about how you can use that

Comment: @gist076923 $C_{∞}$ is closed, together with $\{t_ix_i\}$ bounded it can be proved.